# Raid 1+0 different disk sizes

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, raid10

I have 2 146GB(146,8 in ORCA) sas drives and 2 72GB(73,4 in ORCA) sas drives.
I would like to setup raid 1+0 with these 4 drives.
Is it possible to combine the 146GB and the 72GB drives so I get 218GB?

When I try to setup the raid I only get 136,7GB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOPE.

If you're attempting RAID 1+0 with different sized disks, the lowest-common denominator becomes your base unit size. So your 146GB disks will be treated as 72GB devices.

**4 x 72GB disks in RAID 1+0 == 144GB usable.**

If you need more capacity, [buy bigger disks](http://www.ebay.com/itm/HP-507125-B21-507283-001-146GB-10K-6G-2-5-SAS-DP-HDD-/190648618757?hash=item2c638b0f05:m:mUdAzKK8E319kZl9mDWOvYA).

Answer (score 1):

only possible way how you can get whole capacity is setup 2 raid-1 arrays (one 146GB and second 72GB) and make software jbod raid across those arrays. But you will loose performace boost given by raid-0.

Comment: Thanks, but I already thought about this.